# How to make racket the default implementation in geiser

Tags: emacs, racket, geiser

The geiser documentation suggests that setting `geiser-default-implementation` is one way to prevent `run-geiser` from prompting for a scheme implementation. Another approach suggested by the geiser docs is to set the `geiser-implementations-alist` to the following value:

```
(((regexp "\\.scm$") guile)
((regexp "\\.ss$") racket)
((regexp "\\.rkt$") racket))
```

In neither case do the docs give examples of how to set. I've tried various incantations involving `setq`, `defcustom`, etc., but I continue to be prompted for the desired scheme implementation whenever I run `run-geiser`. The alist doesn't even evaluate properly: for one thing, the regexp function seems not to exist; for another, I'm thinking some sort of quoting is needed to prevent errors on the undefined guile/racket symbols. Would be grateful if someone could give an example of exactly what would need to be added (e.g.) to .emacs in both cases.

Would also like to understand why something like...

```
(setq geiser-default-implementation 'racket)
```

...doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the other implementations from the list of active implementations:

```or-tag-here
(setq geiser-active-implementations '(racket))
```

Comment: The purpose of `geiser-active-implementations` is to allow an implementation to be selected as a function of current file type. The purpose of `geiser-default-implementation` (IIUC) is to specify the implementation to use when current file/buffer isn't sufficient to determine it. Having lots of active implementations configured shouldn't preclude specifying one as the default.